# Does Cassandra has a proxy solution to apache web server?

Tags: apache, cassandra

Similar to what couchbase mod in apache web server, i.e http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Apache_As_a_Reverse_Proxy ?

Comment: Quick note Apache CouchDB and Couchbase are 2 different projects with different architecture, as you can see here http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-vs-couchdb  Couchbase use Memcache protocol to access the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because Cassandra doesn't use http(s) to handle requests. It uses the thrift protocol, or the cql binary protocol in newer versions.

You could try forwarding thrift requests on port 9160 but the more simple answer is using Tomcat or Glassfish to host your webapp which uses Cassandra and proxy requests from tomcat to apache.